# What is the meta_key for user registration date in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, elementor, meta-key

I am pretty new to WordPress.

I am setting up a profile page in WordPress, and I am trying to display the registration date using the meta_key in the profile page to show the date the user joined.

What is the meta_key for user registration date, if it exists, if it does not how can I create a meta-key? Plus how can I return it in the 'DD/MM/YYYY' date format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key for user registered date (actually date and time) is `user_registered`. It's saved as a string in `Y-m-d H:i:s` format. "DD/MM/YYYY" isn't a [PHP/Wordpress date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) format, but I think you mean `d/m/Y`.

How you extract the data will depend on how you're getting the user. So for current user you could try:

```
$registered_date = date( 'd/m/Y', strtotime( wp_get_current_user()->user_registered ) ) ;

echo 'You registered on ' . $registered_date . '.' ;
```

Comment: Thank you, I ended up changing into a short code so that I can add it using Elementor on word press

Comment: function User_regisetered_date() {
 $registered_date = date( 'd/m/Y', strtotime( wp_get_current_user()->user_registered ) ) ;
return $registered_date; 
}
add_shortcode('Registered_date', 'User_regisetered_date');